# How to print the fractional part of the number?

Tags: python-3.x

It's my first question
So, the problem is python rounding. I have seen it, but I dont really know how to get around it.
For example: i have the number 10.34 - I need to receive just fractional part, so 0.34
I had some ideas how to do that. One of this:

```
n = float(input())
print(n - int(n))
```

In case of 10.34 the code give me "0.33999999999999986" instead 0.34.
I have some ideas how to do it with help of strings or another tools, but the task assumes that I need just some basic tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
res = n - int(n)
print(round(res, 10))
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.. Can u explain what is the princip of "round"? Exactly, how the function can determine to what sign should she round it up. Am I right that the function will not round it up if she will receive smt shorter that 10 numbers? Is it possible that the pytnon error rate will be shorter than 10 symbols and she will not consider it?

Comment: round is for rounding, the second argument specifies how many digits you want to keep after dot.

Answer (score 0):

`n = float(input()) n = n - int(n) n = round(n,2)`

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp
The round() function returns a floating point number that is a rounded version of the specified number, with the specified number of decimals.

```
round(number, digits)
```

For your refrence